# TinyMCE local image upload with multiple inline editors

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, image-uploading, tinymce-4

First of all, I am a beginner in tinymce and furthermore not an english native, so sorry for any mistakes ;)

I intend to upload local images (Base64) from multiple inline tinymce(v.4) editors on my site by pressing a button and running the function the tinymce website provides:

```js
tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {
  $.post('ajax/post.php', tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()).done(function() {
    console.log("Uploaded images and posted content as an ajax request.");
  });
});
```

So far it works wery well, but I still have a small problem: It only uploads images from the "active editor" (as stated in the code). If I add an image to an editor, than focus to another on the page and then run the function, it only uploads from the currently active editor, but not my previously added image.

How do I achieve that it uploads from ALL editors on the page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE already has a way to handle inserting local images and getting them to your server:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

If you configure this on each editor when you `init()` the editor these things will get done properly across all editor instances.

Comment: That is what I quoted. But how do I get tinymce to upload the new images from all editors on the page, not just from the active one?

Comment: The editor will automatically do it properly if you use `images_upload_url` in your TinyMCE configuration.  Typically you should not need to write your own upload handler.  The code you referenced above is doing nothing special so I would use `images_upload_url` and make sure it returns the expected JSON.

Comment: thanks! but what triggers the upload then? Lets say `automatic_uploads=false`. If I press the Button, how do I get my inline editors to upload the images if not by running this function? And how do I get a success callback when uploading is finished to procede the program? Sorry I am a bit confused...

Comment: If you are using `automatic_uploads=false` are you wanting to do this at the end before form submission?  If so `tinymce.editors` is an array of all instances and you can loop through each one and run what you need.